# Shopify vendor product invoice emailer

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I dont know where I can ask it but I have one question.

Is there Shopify APP where I have different vendor products and if end-user buys one of vendors product then it Sents invoice to vendor so vendor knows where to send to product. It is like automation tool.